# Any function/attribute in dataframe similar to attribute 'remove' or 'pop'

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Is there any attribute/function for dataframe similar to like 'remove' attribute in series, to remove the 1st occirance of similar indexes in a dataframe.

Dataframe:

```
      a      b     c       d
100   1      2     3       NaN
200   4      5     6       NaN
100   7      9     10      NaN
```

Desired output:(after the desired command)

```
      a      b     c       d

200   4      5     6       NaN
100   7      9     10      NaN
```

Comment: I forget to mention that I want to do the same using labeled index.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `loc` and `duplicated` with `keep='last'`:

```
>>> df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
     a  b   c   d
200  4  5   6 NaN
100  7  9  10 NaN
>>>
```

**Edit:**

```
df.iloc[np.where(df.index.duplicated(keep='last'))]
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I want the same but using 'labeled index'

Comment: @ArnavBhati What you mean by labeled index?

Comment: Labeled index means like: using '100'    eg: df.drop (index =100)    or using positional index like df.drop(df.index[0])

Comment: @ArnavBhati So what's the desired output?

Comment: Desired output should be same as I mentioned above

Comment: Like there are two  rows with labeled index'100', do I want that function and attribute which can like drop or delete only the desired row even if there are duplicates row in my dataframe like, when I used this command:    df.drop(df.index[0]), and df.drop(index=100), it deleted both the rows with index 100, and that is the thing I don't want

Comment: Your code is showing this output: array([ True, False, False])

Comment: @ArnavBhati Edited my answer

Comment: Now it's showing this: 100.   1.   2.   3.    NaN

Comment: @ArnavBhati Edited my answer should work now

Comment: No it's still showing the same previous result .....I think there's no such function or attribute for this